# Link errors using FANN

Tags: c, linker, mingw, fann

I'm trying to build a basic FANN (Fast Artificial Neural Network) project on Windows with MinGW. However, whenever I try to link the executable, I run into a bunch of `undefined reference to` errors. Interestingly, if I don't link the library at all, I get more errors, implying that at least some of the library is working. The code for the file I'm trying to compile and link is:

```
#include "doublefann.h"

int main() {
    const unsigned int num_input_neurons = 9;
    const unsigned int num_output_neurons = 1;
    const unsigned int num_layers = 3;
    const unsigned int num_hidden_neurons = 9;
    const float desired_error = (const float) 0;
    const unsigned int max_epochs = 500000;
    const unsigned int epochs_between_reports = 1000;

    struct fann *ann = fann_create_standard(num_layers,
                                            num_input_neurons,
                                            num_hidden_neurons,
                                            num_output_neurons);

    fann_set_activation_function_hidden(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);
    fann_set_activation_function_output(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);

    fann_train_on_file(ann,
                       "titanic-training.data",
                       max_epochs,
                       epochs_between_reports,
                       desired_error);

    fann_save(ann, "titanic.net");

    fann_destroy(ann);

    return 0;
}
```

and the command I'm using to compile and link is:

```
gcc -Wall -Ifann\src\include titanic-train.c -Lfann\bin -lfanndouble -o titanic-train.exe
```

The errors I'm getting back are:

```
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `fann_set_activation_function_hidden'           
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `fann_set_activation_function_output'           
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `fann_train_on_file'                            
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `fann_save'                                     
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `fann_destroy'                                  
c:/fragileprograms/mingw-native/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o: bad reloc address 0x64 in section `.rdata'                                                                                                                 
c:/fragileprograms/mingw-native/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation                   
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I don't link the library at all, I instead get:

```
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyOO3jL.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `fann_create_standard'
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `fann_set_activation_function_hidden'           
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `fann_set_activation_function_output'           
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `fann_train_on_file'                            
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `fann_save'                                     
C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o:titanic-train.c:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `fann_destroy'                                  
c:/fragileprograms/mingw-native/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\kunkelwe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsWQg66.o: bad reloc address 0x64 in section `.rdata'                                                                                                                 
c:/fragileprograms/mingw-native/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation                   
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Edit:**

As per Haroogan's request, I ran `nm fanndouble.lib`. The output is rather extensive, so rather than paste it all here, I've made it available via pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vybFhEcX

I'm not familiar with `nm`, but it appears that the missing symbols do exist in the file.

**Edit #2:**

The contents of doublefann.h are: http://pastebin.com/mrHKJi8C

and the contents of fann.h, which it includes are: http://pastebin.com/gTrHCYAg

Could the problem just be solved by recompiling the library with MinGW?

**Edit #3:**

Making the changes that Haroogan suggested worked! In addition to those changes, I had to modify the CMakeLists.txt file for FANN by adding:

```
if (WIN32)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DFANN_DLL_EXPORTS)
endif (WIN32)
```

Then, running `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"` and then `mingw32-make` in the root of the project produced a file, libdoublefann.dll, that when linked against and included in the directory of the .exe, allowed me, *finally*, to run my program.

Comment: Run `nm libfanndouble.a`, and see if the missing symbols are in fact defined in the library. Update your question with the results when you are done, so that we can think what to do next.

Comment: @Haroogan: Done. It's fanndouble.lib, by the way, not libfanndouble.a

Comment: This is classical problem with **[name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)** which is different across compilers. Obviously, both `fanndouble.lib` and `fanndouble.dll` were produced by the MSVC compiler, and therefore now you have trouble directly linking with MinGW because of different name mangling conventions. But don't worry, we'll fix it. First of all, let's have a look at your `floatfann.h`.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't realize that the code on here said `"floatfann.h"`; I had changed it from `"doublefann.h"` to test if linking worked with the fannfloat library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `doublefann.h` on the line #116:

```
#if (_MSC_VER > 1300)
```

change to:

```
#if (_MSC_VER > 1300) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)
```

Furthermore, on the line #121:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (defined(FANN_USE_DLL) || defined(FANN_DLL_EXPORTS))
```

change to:

```
#if (defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)) && \
    (defined(FANN_USE_DLL) || defined(FANN_DLL_EXPORTS))
```

Comment: Thanks. I've run into a (probably) unrelated problem with MinGW, so it might be a little while before I can do this.